# On the directing nature of these groups in electrophilic aromatic substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance, hyperconjugation

These three groups are listed in our workbook. I don't know the answer and our teacher isn't sure either:

[image: Three substituents]

(each has a free valency through which it is attached to a benzene ring):

1. Diphenylhalomethyl
2. Difluoromethyl
3. Dichloromethyl

Now, I've read and understood this question - [How does hyperconjugation lead to the directing properties of alkyl group?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24591/how-does-hyperconjugation-lead-to-the-directing-properties-of-alkyl-group) Therefore, I think that the groups 2,3 are deactivating (due to -I effect of fluorines and chlorines) yet o/p directing due to hyperconjugation with the H atom. On the other hand, the first group should be meta directing since it has only -I effect and no +/-M or hyperconjugation.

I googled for the complete list of directing groups but I could not find these types of groups.

> Is my reasoning - and hence answer - correct? Or is there another answer, and why?

Comment: Is 1 a deactivator meta director? 2 deactivator , o/p? 3 deactivator meta? If any of those is correct let me know. I might be thinking on the rightish track.

Comment: @AvnishKabaj I don't know the answer :(

Comment: I agree with you, on the first group being a meta directing group. But I believe that the degree of hyperconjugation in the second and the third group is very low (due to a single hydrogen atom). Carbon is quite electrophilic in both the cases and hence they must behave like meta directing groups just like CF3.